# can i hardware raid 0 windows 10 alongside ubuntu?

Tags: boot

I am new to Linux.

I would like to dual-boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 when it comes out next month. I game on my pc, and am using two Intel 480GB SSD's in RAID-0. (motherboard raid) yet Ubuntu cannot install onto the array, when doing the automatic install.

It gives me one of two different errors: either I get a box with question marks all over it or it asks me whether was this partition previously part of an MBT table or something like that and won't let me continue.

I'm new at this and don't understand the file systems that Linux requires and how they need to be set up yet.

Is it possible to have both Windows and Ubuntu installed on the same raided drive or should I consider having Ubuntu install on a separate drive?

Comment: Your question is too unclear to be answerable in a q/a format, but it sounds like you have what is called a fake raid, and want to dual boot windows and ubuntu.  If you are asking if this is possible, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use RAID 0: it's a disaster waiting to happen: if only ONE of your 2 drives fails, the entire RAID array fails and you lose everything!
2. Yes, Ubuntu and Windows 10 can be installed on the same drive as this is how I'm running right now.

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey check mark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask